# Just to be sure: cookiecutter-django does not have a logout endpoint, right?

Tags: cookiecutter-django

Cookiecutter-django have endpoints /auth-token/ to get a token and /api/users/me/ for getting user info. But it does not seem to have a logout endpoint. Am I right?

And, if the serverside logout is needed, i will need to write it.

Can you confirm?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are referring to the DRF part of the cookie cutter. There is no logout, what you want to do is write some endpoint that will delete/invalidate the instance of the respective `Token` model from your database.

If you are referring to the non-DRF part, there is a logout at `/accounts/logout/`.